# Variables in batch

Tags: variables, batch-file, batch-choice

I am trying to create a code that can process a variable based on a choice in a way like this:

```
set item1=ring
set item2=deadhead
set item3=bloodstainedmap
set item4=strangebox
cls
echo 1) %item1%
echo 2) %item2%
echo 3) %item3%
echo 4) %item4%
echo. 
echo Which Item do you wish to look at?
choice /c 1234 /n >nul
if %errorlevel%==1 goto itemin
if %errorlevel%==2 goto itemin
if %errorlevel%==3 goto itemin
if %errorlevel%==4 goto itemin

:itemin
cls
echo %item%errorlevel%%
::^^^^ this part here should read "ring" if i selected 1. It reads "errorlevel"
```

Obviously, I would like the Item to shown correctly when it loads the variable....

Any help?

### A.S.C

Comment: if (for some reason) you want to avoid [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028), you can also use `call echo %%item%errorlevel%%%` (you have to parse the command twice - first to expand `errorlevel` to its value, second to expand `itemX`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion for this task:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "item1=ring"
set "item2=deadhead"
set "item3=bloodstainedmap"
set "item4=strangebox"
cls
echo 1) %item1%
echo 2) %item2%
echo 3) %item3%
echo 4) %item4%
echo(
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
:UserChoice
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C 1234 /N /M "Which item do you wish to look at?"
if not errorlevel 1 goto UserChoice
set "item=!item%ERRORLEVEL%!"
endlocal & set "item=%item%"
echo %item%
endlocal
```

The user prompt is repeated if the user presses <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> and answers the prompt by `cmd.exe` to exit processing of the batch file with <kbd>N</kbd> in which case the condition `if not errorlevel 1` is true as the exit code of **CHOICE** is `0` in this special use case.

It would be of course also possible to enable [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) already at top of the batch file. It must be just taken into account that all lines are parsed twice on doing that and `!` is interpreted everywhere as start/end of a delayed expanded environment variable reference.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `choice /?`
- `cls /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See also:

- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/)
- [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564)
- [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564)
- DosTips forum topic: [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774)

Answer (score 1):

As a supplement to [@Mofi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3074564/mofi)'s [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66241131/12343998):

The Choice command can be executed within a for /F loop allowing the choice option to be used directly as opposed to assessing errorlevels. The /N no prompt switch must be used, and the use of the /M custom prompt switch must be excluded.

The syntax for getting the actual key pressed as opposed to the errorlevel is:

```bat
@ECHO Off & Goto :main
====================================
:::  Script Break - Functions    :::
====================================

====================================
:main                            :::  
====================================
:::      Macro Definitions       :::
====================================
(Set \n=^^^

%= Newline var \n for macro definition - Do not modify. =%)
 If "!![" == "[" (
  Echo/DelayedExpansion Not permitted prior to Macro Definition.
  Exit /B 0
 )
========================================== ::: MENU macro prep and Definition :::
rem /* Key index list Allows 36 menu options. Component of Menu Macro /*
 Set "ChoList=0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
rem /* Menu macro Usage: %Menu% "quoted" "list of" "options"
==========================================
==== Set Menu=For %%n in (1 2)Do if %%n==2 (%\n%
%= Output Dividing Line                 =%  Echo(!DIV!%\n%
%= Reset CH# index value for Opt[#]     =%  Set "CH#=0"%\n%
%= Undefine choice option key list      =%  Set "CHCS="%\n%
%= For Each in list;                    =%  For %%G in (!Options!)Do (%\n%
%= For Option Index value               =%   For %%i in (!CH#!)Do (%\n%
%= Build the Choice key list and Opt[#] =%    Set "CHCS=!CHCS!!ChoList:~%%i,1!"%\n%
%= array using the character at the     =%    Set "Opt[!ChoList:~%%i,1!]=%%~G"%\n%
%= current substring index. Display.    =%    Echo([!ChoList:~%%i,1!] %%~G%\n%
%= Increment Opt[#] Index var CH#       =%    Set /A "CH#+=1"%\n%
%= Close CH# loop                       =%   )%\n%
%= Close Options loop                   =%  )%\n%
%= Output Dividing Line                 =%  Echo(!DIV!%\n%
%= Select option by character index     =%  For /F "Delims=" %%o in ('Choice /N /C:!CHCS!')Do (%\n%
%= Assign return var OPTION with the    =%   Set "Option=!Opt[%%o]!"%\n%
%= value selected from Opt[CH#] array.  =%  )%\n%
%= Capture Macro input - Options List   =% )Else Set Options=
========================================== ::: End Menu Definition :::
rem /* Get console width for dividing line. */
 for /F "usebackq tokens=2* delims=: " %%W in (`mode con ^| findstr Columns`) do Set /A     "Console_Width=%%W"
rem /* Enable environment for macro expansion */
 Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem /* Build dividing line. */
 Set "DIV="&For /L %%i in (2 1 %Console_Width%)Do Set "DIV=!DIV!-"
====================================
:::         Script Body          :::
====================================
rem /* Optional - Define an Options list. */
 Set "Loot[1]= "ring" "dead head" "blood stained map" "strange box""
:menu
 CLS & Title %~n0
 %Menu% "exit" %Loot[1]%
 If "!Option!" == "exit" (Endlocal & Goto :Eof)Else Echo/You chose !Option!
rem /* Optional - remove selected option from list of options. Options should be Doublequoted with leading whitespace. */
 Set "Loot[1]=!Loot[1]: "%Option%"=!"
rem /* Do whatever you want with your option here. Execute it, use options as label names to call etc. */
 Pause
Goto :menu
```

Comment: I like what I am seeing here, however how does it work? this is perfect for example, when using The said items, and the item is removed form inventory

Comment: Batch macro's take advantage of the way cmd parses scripts to use variables as functions. To begin understanding how the interpreter works, See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/12343998). To understand the creation and use of Batch Macro's with arguments visit this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/12343998).

Comment: The particular steps this macro takes to achieve the task are described in the inline comments during the macro's definition.